# Can anyone explain why firefox crops this SVG image?

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Can anyone explain why firefox crops this SVG image?

It's within a container and being scaled to fit by CSS.

I'm using `<symbol>` and `<use>`.

```css
.container {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none">
  <symbol id="icon_triangleup" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M12.8,5.4c-0.377-0.504-1.223-0.504-1.6,0l-9,12c-0.228,0.303-0.264,0.708-0.095,1.047 C2.275,18.786,2.621,19,3,19h18c0.379,0,0.725-0.214,0.895-0.553c0.169-0.339,0.133-0.744-0.095-1.047L12.8,5.4z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
<div class="container">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon_triangleup"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you why, as in, how to fix it. But not why Chrome seems to ignore what's causing the issue in Firefox.

Firefox is using the `24px` width and height set on the `<symbol>` element, so remove those and the symbol will expand to fill the space of it's container.

You can always set the `width` and `height` on the `<use>` element if you want the individual instances of the symbol to be different sizes.

```css
.container {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none">
  <symbol id="icon_triangleup" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M12.8,5.4c-0.377-0.504-1.223-0.504-1.6,0l-9,12c-0.228,0.303-0.264,0.708-0.095,1.047 C2.275,18.786,2.621,19,3,19h18c0.379,0,0.725-0.214,0.895-0.553c0.169-0.339,0.133-0.744-0.095-1.047L12.8,5.4z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
<div class="container">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon_triangleup"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```